# Cannot parse SQL result count from Logic App

Tags: sql, json, azure-logic-apps

I run this simple query in Logic App using the "Execute a SQL query (V2)" connector to find out if a number exists in my table.

```
select count(*) from users where user_number='724-555-5555';
```

If the number exist, I get this JSON , but somehow I cant parse it.

```
[
  {
    "": 1
  }
]
```

Any idea how to simply retrieve 0 or 1 ?
Thanks
David

Comment: Does the `user_number`  column have a `UNIQUE` constraint or index?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an explicit column name:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS cnt
FROM
    users
WHERE
    user_number = '724-555-5555';
```

That will give you this result:

```
[ { "cnt": 1 } ]
```

...which is valid JSON.